# Given $X\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y\sim\text{Ber}\left(\frac Xn\right)$, find $E[X\mid Y]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

> If $X\sim \operatorname{Binom}(n,p)$ and $Y\sim \operatorname{Ber}\left(\frac Xn\right)$, then find $E[X\mid Y]$.

Is there a name for such a random variable $Y$, where its distribution depends on another r.v. ?

I got after some lengthy calculation $$P(Y=0)=1-p$$
$$P(Y=1)=p$$

I don't know over which variable to sum ? I must get a function in terms of $Y$

Then $$E[X\mid Y=1]=\sum_\limits{???}\frac{P(X=k)P(Y=1\mid X=k)}{P(Y=1)}$$

what I know, (assuming there are $n$ trials with $n\ge k$)

$$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

$$P(Y=1\mid X=k)=\frac{k}{n}$$

It is also inappropriate to set $Y=1$ instead of $Y=m$ for some $m$, otherwise I cannot recognize $Y$ in the formula. How to remedy this ?

EDIT: When the variable goes from $k=0$ to $n$ I obtain the following,

$$E[X\mid Y=1]=np-p+1,\quad E[X\mid Y=0]=p(n-1)$$

so it seems legitimate to combine these 2 in the following way,

$$E[X\mid Y]=(np-p+1)Y+\left(p(n-1)\right)(1-Y)$$

Is this true ?

Comment: @Gae.S. The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is given: $Y$ is Bernoulli with probability $X/n$.

Comment: Hint: You know that $X$ has support $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist So the variable runs from $k=0$ to $n$ ?

Comment: Yes. Now repeat the exercise for $Y=0$, and that should give you $E[X\mid Y]$.

Comment: Your last line is exactly correct. (Assuming all the preceding calculations are correct. I did not work through them to check, but conceptually, what you’ve done should be correct.)

Comment: Sanity check should give $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid Y]]=\mathbb EX$. It did not before your edit, but now it does. Good job! I was just about ready with my answer at the moment that your edit appeared. You can take as a confirmation now. Not so much an improvement. Observe that $(np-p+1)Y+(p(n-1))(1-Y)=Y+(n-1)p$ (a bit simpler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this answer for convenience $q:=1-p$ and $Z\sim\mathsf{Bin}\left(n-1,p\right)$.

Working out: $$P\left(Y=1\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}P\left(Y=1\mid X=k\right)P\left(X=k\right)$$
we find $P\left(Y=1\right)=p$ and consequently $P\left(Y=0\right)=q$.

Then for $k=1,\dots,n$:

$$P\left(X=k\mid Y=1\right)p=P\left(X=k\wedge Y=1\right)=P\left(Y=1\mid X=k\right)P\left(X=k\right)=\frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}$$
leading to: $$P\left(X=k\mid Y=1\right)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}q^{n-k}$$

This reveals that $\left(X-1\mid Y=1\right)\stackrel{d}{=}Z$ so that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y=1\right]=1+\mathbb{E}\left[X-1\mid Y=1\right]=1+\mathbb{E}Z=1+\left(n-1\right)p\tag1$$

Similarly we find for $k=0,\dots,n-1$:$$P\left(X=k\mid Y=0\right)q=P\left(X=k\wedge Y=0\right)=P\left(Y=0\mid X=k\right)P\left(X=k\right)=\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}$$
so that $$P\left(X=k\mid Y=0\right)=\binom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-1-k}$$

This reveals that $\left(X\mid Y=0\right)\stackrel{d}{=}Z$ so that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y=0\right]=\mathbb{E}Z=\left(n-1\right)p\tag2$$

Based on $(1)$ and $(2)$ we conclude: $$\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y\right]=Y+\left(n-1\right)p$$

---

**Edit**:

More simple approach that arose later and was inspired by the outcome $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=Y+(n-1)p$.

Let us set $X=Y+Z$ where $X,Y$ are independent with $Y\sim\mathsf{Bern}\left(p\right)$
and $Z\sim\mathsf{Bin}\left(n-1,p\right)$.

Then observe that $X\sim\mathsf{Bin}\left(n,p\right)$ and that $\left(Y\mid X\right)\sim\mathsf{Bern}\left(\frac{X}{n}\right)$.

This is exactly the situation prescribed in your question except that
you stated that $Y\sim\mathsf{Bern}\left(\frac{X}{n}\right)$.

That is actually not correct as **Graham Kemp** made clear in his answer.

In this situation we find directly: $$\mathbb{E}\left[X\mid Y\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[Y+Z\mid Y\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid Y\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[Z\mid Y\right]=Y+\mathbb{E}Z=Y+\left(n-1\right)p$$where the third equality is based on independence.

Comment: And of course, $Y+p(n-1)~+(p(n-1)-p(n-1))Y~=~(np-p+1)Y+\left(p(n-1)\right)(1-Y)$ Thus confirming the OP's result.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Indeed it does now. This answer was published at almost exactly the same moment that the question was edited (and corrected).

Comment: Just to let you know: I have added a more simple approach making lots of calculations redundant. Especially the nice outcome $Y+(n-1)p$ was inspiring.

Answer (score 3):

> > If $X\sim Binom(n,p)$ and $Y\sim Ber(X/n)$ then find $E[X|Y]$
>
> Is there a name for such a random variable $Y$, where its distribution depends on another r.v. ?

You have not in fact been given the distribution for $Y$.   What you have been given a *conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$*, which is more commonly written: $$(Y\mid X)\sim \mathcal{Ber}(X/n)$$

As you have found, the *actual* distribution for $Y$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p$, that is: $$Y\sim\mathcal{Ber}(p)$$

Comment: And if we start with $X=B_1+\cdots+B_n$ where the $B_i$ are iid $\sim\mathsf{Ber}(p)$ (so that $X\sim\mathsf{Bin}(n,p)$) and we set $Y:=B_1$ then we are exactly in this situation. This also makes the outcome $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=Y+(n-1)p$ more understandable.